# Mysql migration tool, source parameter string | connection string for sql server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, migration

I always got failed to "fetching of list failed error".

This is my connection string in ASP.NET

```
"Data Source=maywood\XSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=maywood_test;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

What exactly should I input at MySQL migration tool for source parameter string

FYI,'maywood' is my computer name and I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have integrated `Integrated Security=SSPI` set -- perhaps you should try setting the UID and Password manually to values that you know are correct.

```
Data Source=maywood\XSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=maywood_test;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Integrated Security uses the credentials from the Windows system that you're using to log in -- these credentials might not be valid for the database you're trying to access.